# filter level 4 array nested object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this document structure:

```
 [
  {
"_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
"arr1": [
  {
    "arr2": [
      {
        "arr3": [
          {
            "field3": 3,
            "id5": 1
          },
          {
            "field3": 2,
            "id5": 2
          }
        ],
        "id3": 1
      },
      {
        "arr3": [
          {
            "arr4": [
              {
                "field4": "I need this",
                "id4": 1
              }
            ],
            "field3": 1,
            "id5": 1
          },
          {
            "field3": 2,
            "id5": 2
          }
        ],
        "id3": 2
      }
      ],
    "field2": 1,
    "id2": 1
      }
    ],
"id": 1
  }
 ]
```

And I need to filter the objects inside arr4 nested array , please, advice how this can be done best and without $unwind operations since collection is 500GB compressed and it takes alot of time with unwinds?

expected output:

```
 {field4:"I need this" ,id4:1}
```

Comment: If it has to be dynamic, you need to change the schema.

Comment: I can't  change , I can extract  only ...

Comment: Is level fixed?

Comment: Yes , except the documents missing array3...